# How can a class get an instance of itself?

Tags: java, jframe

Today, I was working on a tutorial with integrating buttons into a ground up built game engine. This is the code that requests win.

```
public class ButtonEvent{

    private Window win;

    public ButtonEvent(){

        this.win = Window.getWindow();

    }

    /*Other methods*/

}
```

I watched the whole video through, but the guy who went over the class never mentioned what he did to his Window class to do this. In that video he happened to click the window class and then click the next class and in that time, when I paused the video, I saw his getWindow() method. Which I wrote below.

```
public class Window extends Canvas{

public Window win; //I tried doing this

    /*Other methods*/ 

    public static Window getWindow(){
        return win;
    }

}
```

Can someone explain to me how he does this? I know the question is kind of vague, but it's all I have to work with.

Thanks!

Comment: You have to create an instance somewhere.

Comment: No, if your Window class is going to have a Window field, the **field** should probably be static. But more importantly don't use that tutorial since it is woefully out of date if it is having you learn AWT.

Comment: I'm not using AWT, everything is a self made class, it just happens to have the same name.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to pass `ButtonEvent` a reference to the `Window` via the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the singleton pattern to ensure that only one instance of `Window` is created and used throughout the application.  Note that singletons are considered an "anti-pattern" meaning that there's usually a better way to go about it, such as using container-managed objects (see PicoContainer, Spring IoC, etc).

```
public class Window {
    private static Window INSTANCE = null;

    public static Window getWindow() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new Window();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public Window win;
```

to

```
private static Window win = new Window();
```

And you will have the proper local visibility for `getWindow()` to see the `Window` field, and it will be initialized by calling the *implicit* empty constructor that the compiler inserts (that's the assignment of `new Window`).

Comment: That works if I have an empty constructor which is great. That solves half of my issue. What happens when I have a full constructor of (String title, int width, int height)?

Comment: you may define a `private static Window win;` and initialize it in a `static` method, like in a singleton

Comment: @Kenneth where are the title, width, and height being provided from?  Are they passed in from the commandline, a properties file, or are you just hardcoding them in the source code?